# VBA Macro Error when trying to Print Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have a macro that I want to cycle through sheets in excel and print each sheet based on cell values B5 and B6, the problem is that if the value of B5 or B6 is 0 then the macro crashes and shows an error, is there a way that I can get it to skip to the next part of the code if the value of B5 is 0?

Any help much appreciated!

```
Sub printlabels()

Worksheets("1033").Activate
iNumCopies = Range("B5").Value
ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=iNumCopies

Worksheets("1090").Activate
iNumCopies = Range("B6").Value
ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=iNumCopies

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use If statement

```
if iNumCopies > 0 Then
     ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=iNumCopies
End If
```

In addition, it will take a lot of time if you write different code for each sheet. Instead looping through sheets is advised.

```
For Each xSheet in ThisWorkbook.Sheets
   iNumCopies = xSheet.Range("B5").Value        ' Or iNumCopies = xSheet.Range("B6").Value

   if iNumCopies > 0 Then
         xSheet.PrintOut Copies:=iNumCopies
   End If
next xSheet
```

You don't have to activate sheet.